# Searching in several mysql tables

Tags: mysql

There is a MySQL database with several(but we don't know how much) tables. The only thing I know about them, is that all of them have a prefix 'pref'. So how can I search in every table, if a don't know their names ? Can you help me with the query ?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: How come you know so little about the database? Is it yours? Sounds dodgy to me.

Comment: I'm writing a log pasers for the program, which automatically creates a new table every time it starts. So that's why i know so little about my database/

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to take out all the tables names starting with prefix 'pref'.
If YEs, you can run following query:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'pref%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query information_schema.tables to know all the tables starting with 'pref' and query them individually.
Use a stored procedure if this is a frequent task.